# Firebase Security Rule with attribute in database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need security rules for my firebase-app.
My Data looks like this

```
{
     owner = "djskjfskdjf",
     data = "some data"
}
```

Collection Path is `/Data/`
I want that users that are authenticated users can read and create documents in this collection. To edit or delete documents, I want that the uid in the field owner is the same as the request.auth.id.

According to firebase documentation this should work:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /Data/{document=**} {
            allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
            allow delete, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to update a field in simulation it gives me the error:
`Error: simulator.rules line [5], column [51]. Property resource is undefined on object.`

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation and make an attempt to implement the rules you just described.  Edit the post with the specific code that doesn't work the way you expect. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Edited my post with what you asked for

Comment: Have you tried just `resource.data.owner` instead of `request.resource.data.owner`?

Comment: That gives a null value error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your request isn't sending the all the required fields you're checking in rules, then `request.resource.data.owner` wont work (like if you are just sending data but not owner with the request).

You should use the below style to match an existing object in the database. It won't matter if the request omits the owner info.
`allow delete: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;`

Comment: That did it. Thank you